# Treating an operator as a variable in an Integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I am a bit new to calculus and I am trying to understand Leibniz notation, since I am taking physics and I am required to use that instead of primes. However, it confuses me how people use "d" (which I believe is an operator?) as a variable:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x)$$

$$dy=f(x)dx$$
$$\int{dy}=\int{f(x)dx}$$
$$y=\int{f(x)dx}$$

I don't understand this.  First, it seems to me d is used as a variable. Also, I don't get how they simplify:

$$\int{dy}=y$$

Can someone explain how the operator d works? and how these operations with integrals work.

Comment: "d" is not being used as a variable here. Think about what function you are integrating on the left hand side.

Comment: I am integrating the derivate of y over derivate of x, but wouldn't integrating y would be 1/2(y^2)

Comment: There is a difference between a derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and the differential $dy$ or $dx$. The differential in an integral tells us what to integrate with respect to. On the left hand side you are looking at the integral of $1dy$

Comment: Notice that the step from the second equation to the third equation is not valid, since in the LHS you're integrating with respect to $y$ and in the RHS you're integrating with respect to $x$, so the equality shouldn't be preserved in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator is not $d$, the operator is $\frac{d}{dx}$.

The method that you portray is a very informal way to solve differential equations usually used in engineering classes.

The formal procedure is the following:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x)$$

$$\int_{t_0}^t\frac{dy}{dx}dx=\int_{t_0}^tf(x)dx.$$

Using the sustitution rule for integrals:

$$\int_{y(t_0)}^{y(t)}dy=\int_{t_0}^tf(x)dx$$

$$y(t)-y(t_0)=\int_{t_0}^tf(x)dx,$$

so that

$$y(t)=y(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^tf(x)dx.$$

Comment: Could you explain what an operator is? and how does the function f(x) = dy/dx. Does this mean that f(x) equal to the derivative of dy/dx?

Comment: Roughly speaking, an operator is a function whose domain is an infinite dimensional space. Since these spaces can be thought as sets whose elements are functions, an operator can also be thought as a "metafunction" which transforms functions in to other functions (the derivative, the Fourier transform, the Laplace transform) or into something else (the definite integral, the evaluation). For you second question, the answer is yes.